# print account link field in node

Tags: php, drupal

I am having a hard time trying to figure this out. Can someone help me please?

I have created a custom link field in Account Settings (Drupal 7) called "field_twitter" (that's the machine name). I would like to print the output of that field in node.tpl. Basically, I want the node author to have his twitter handle displayed. This is what I have so far and it wont work:

```
 $node = $variables['node']; $author = user_load($node->uid); $twitter = field_get_items('user', $author, 'field_twitter');
  $userid = $node->uid; print render($twitter[0]['value']);
```

I've even tried the following code and it wont work

```
  print render($content['field_twitter']);
```

Please help me out, I am losing my mind! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to print the node array first and $node is an object of array.

So try this

```
$node->content->field_twitter
```

Comment: Like this?    print render($node->content->field_twitter);

Comment: I still cant get this to work, if anyone can help :)